# How can I add ParallaxEffect without UIInterpolatingMotionEffect class

Tags: swift, parallax, cmmotionmanager, swift4.2

how can i do a parallaxeffect without the UIInterpolatingMotionEffect class. Only with the Acceleration in the iPhone? I want the Effect when you tilt your phone up that the image goes up to. Just normal parallaxEffect

I've tried this:

```
func setupParallax() {
        let motion = CMMotionManager()
        motion.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        parallaxImage.frame.origin.x = CGFloat((motion.accelerometerData?.acceleration.x)!)
        parallaxImage.frame.origin.y = CGFloat((motion.accelerometerData?.acceleration.y)!)
    }
```

Comment: There’s not a lot of information here. You should add what you have tried etc.., and what effect you want.

Comment: check now. i've added

Comment: Is there any reason you don’t want to use UIMotionEffect?

Comment: I'm learning atm with a course and the challenge was to do that. The problem is that so many people ask questions that they dont answer

Answer (score 1):

Use Core Motion. Ideally your motion manager’s reference frame should be `CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical`, so that you can obtain the current attitude with respect to the starting attitude by calling `multiply(byInverseOf:)`. To do so, run a repeating Timer and poll your motion manager’s device motion to get its attitude. Now use that to adjust the transform of your view.

Comment: can you give me an example. i dont get it what youre saying

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you, no. You asked how to detect the tilt of the device so that you can perform a parallax-style shift on your view without using UIInterpolatingMotionEffect, and that's my answer as to how to do that.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Swift. It has to do with iOS. I'm not saying should have any idea about it; I'm pointing you in a direction. You don't have to go in that direction. But if you want to, then start learning about Core Motion.